# how to Quick Look text files with custom file extensions in Finder

Tags: finder, preview, text, quicklook

When I have .txt files or .py files, I can Quick Look those files in Finder. I have .jl files that are codes written in the Julia Language. Of course they are text files. They will open in a text editor like Sublime Text. How can I Quick Look these .jl files in Finder?

Comment: how do you preview in Finder? do you mean the Quick Look ?

Comment: I think if one works the other will.

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://superuser.com/questions/230204/make-os-xs-quick-look-work-for-custom-file-extensions

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yes, I meant Quick Look. I will modify the question.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23561/is-there-a-quicklook-preview-for-plain-text-files-with-unknown-extensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [glance](https://github.com/chamburr/glance#installation), it does work for me.

Comment: Thanks! it works!

Answer (score 6):

**update**

With the new macOS release in 2019, the macOS Catalina, this approach is banned.

---

Install [QLStephen](http://whomwah.github.io/qlstephen/), a QuickLook plugin that enables viewing of text files with arbitrary filetypes.

To install, copy the `*.qlgenerator` file to `~/Library/QuickLook/`.

Comment: still works fine for me in Catalina. Just follows the instructions to get around the security warnings

Comment: Still works with Ventura

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @SebastianHallumClarke

I didn't find `~/Library/QuickLook/`
but I went to the [github page of QL Stephen](http://whomwah.github.io/qlstephen/) and enter `brew cask install qlstephen` in the command line and it installed QL Stephen successfully

Comment: It is now ``brew install --cask qlstephen``, but it doesn't seem to work anymore.