# How do I associate arbitrary filetypes with the quicklook plain-text generator without installing third party code?

Tags: preview, quicklook

I have files I'd like to preview with quicklook, but I don't want a special plugin - I'm happy with the existing text generator.

I think the generator is this

```
public.plain-text -> /System/Library/QuickLook/Text.qlgenerator (965.1)
```

(from `qlmanage -m plugins`)

I know the plain-text plugin can handle my files because changing the extension to txt or even md instantly provides a preview in quicklook.

- I'm on Ventura 13.2.1.
- I don't want to install or develop a plugin for what are essentially plain text files.

Example files might be: units_by_month.csv or admission.hl7

EDIT:  user @Allan quite helpfully provided an actual **answer** in the comments below. He is a gentleman. I'm disappointed it was not the answer I am looking for but it was the answer I needed. Thank you @Allan

Comment: Could you explain your question better? I can't quite understand it.

Comment: @thinkr see the title, basically they want to have the plain-text QuickLook generator also work for .csv and .hl7.

Comment: @nohillside ohhhh alright I see. I didn't understood from the title neither before, that's why I asked.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163428/how-to-quick-look-text-files-with-custom-file-extensions-in-finder

Comment: As stated in the question I don't want to install untrusted third party code. Just extend the list of extensions that are treated as plain text.
The list of extensions are not limited to .hl7 and csv. they are just examples chosen to emphasise the text requirement. They could easily be source code text files.

Comment: >  they want to have the plain-text QuickLook generator

no. Specifically change the file extensions associated

Comment: Since the entire QL functionality is based on *code* (a plugin), there’s quite literally no way for you to do this.

Comment: @Allan thank you for providing an *answer*. You are a gentleman.